# Container Height 0, no Matter How Big Children

Tags: jquery, css, height, parent

Self-Explanatory. I've tried quite a few methods to try and fix this. The container holds my main content, but it's height won't hold, forcing my footer halfway up the page behind it. My navbar just changes the display for each "page" to none, and then to block depending on which

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav_container">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav_services"><i></i><span>SERVICES</span></li>
        <li class="nav_home nav_active"><i></i><span>HOME</span></li>
        <li class="nav_contact"><i></i><span>CONTACT</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="main_container">
   <div id="services_container">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
   </div>
   <div id="home_container">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
   </div>
   <div id="contact_container">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
   </div>
</div>

<div id="footer_container">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main_container {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
#contact_container, #home_container, #services_container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px #d4d1ff solid;
    font-size: 17px;
}
#footer_container {
    height: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #080175;
    border-top: #1F242A;
    -moz-transition: top 1s ease;
    -o-transition: top 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s ease;
    transition: top 1s ease;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
function page_handler() {
$('.nav_services').click(function () {
    if ($('.nav_services:not(.nav_active)')) {
        $('#services_container').css({
            display: 'block'
        });
        $('#home_container, #contact_container').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
    }
});
$('.nav_home').click(function () {
    if ($('.nav_home:not(.nav_active)')) {
        $('#home_container').css({
            display: 'block'
        });
        $('#services_container, #contact_container').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
    }
});
$('.nav_contact').click(function () {
    if ($('.nav_contact:not(.nav_active)')) {
        $('#contact_container').css({
            display: 'block'
        });
        $('#services_container, #home_container').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
        initialize();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: *footer* ? what *footer*? I mean try to create a previewable issue cause this is all I see: http://jsbin.com/goqokicuqi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Also, you added that jQuery... I don't know why. There's nothing related in that JS with the above HTML and CSS code.

Comment: Updated my code. I added the jQuery so you'd see what was happening with the content inside the main_container.

Comment: I'm editing the file locally so I can't just share my entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ducufapiha/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

Your children elements, being `position:absolute;` are removed from the natural document flow and the `main_container` parent cannot contain them properly.

- assign a class `class="content"` to all your child elements (that's what classes are for)

```
<div id="main_container">
   <div class="content" id="services_container">SERVICES Lorem ipsum</div>
   <div class="content" id="home_container">HOME Lorem ipsum</div>
   <div class="content" id="contact_container">CONTACT Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

- set that `.content` to `position:relative;`
- Make visible only the first one using CSS: `.content + .content {display:none;}`

```
#main_container {
  position:relative;
  overflow:auto;
}
.content{
  position:relative;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px #d4d1ff solid;
}
.content + .content{
   display:none; /* HIDES ALL BUT FIRST ONE */
}
#footer_container {
  height: 180px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #080175;
}
```

than with **jQuery** you can show / hide the desired `.content` .

To achieve that, add an Anchor like

```
               <a href="#home_container">HOME</a>
```

that will reference to the

```
<div class="content" id="home_container">Lorem....</div>
```

On click on that anchor first hide all the `.content` elements and than show the one which ID matches the clicked anchor `href`:

```
// Get all content elements
var $content = $(".content");

$("#nav_container a").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    $content.hide(); // Hide all
    $(id).show(); // Show only the one which ID matches the anchor href
});
```

Comment: I assume I'm removing the position, left, width, and display property from #services_container, #home_container, and #contact_container?

Comment: And as far as the jQuery, how am I selecting which one is hidden vs. which one is displayed? :nth-child?

Comment: @Karmaxdw added all the code and examples you need. if you have questions feel free to ask.

Comment: You're very helpful thank you. I have just one last issue. The main_container has indeed taken to the height of the children, but the height of the children's content is now almost no height. For example, #home_container's background is barely below it's title.

Comment: @Karmaxdw add `overflow:auto;` to the `.content` element. (to fix the issue of `float`ed content elements (images, text))

Comment: Thanks for everything!